# Python Firebase How to check whether a file exists on firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Hi I wondering whether it was possible to check whether a file exists on firebase storage using python. Here are a couple ways of doing it for other languages.

[How to check if a file exists in Firebase storage from your android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567626/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-firebase-storage-from-your-android-application)

[how to check if file exists in Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage)

What is the equivalent method for python.

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using the request module and using the public url for the file. Hope this helps anyone else facing the same issue.

```
import requests
from firebase_admin import storage


#Creates the blob reference to file on the server
bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob("firebase/path/to/file")

#Requests the file using the public url
r = requests.head(blob.public_url)
            
#Whether the file exists or not on the server
fileExists = (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
```

> Edit

Thanks to some helpful pointers you can use

```
fileExists = blob.exists()
```

Which means you no longer require the requests module